# adding current date as a parameter to a query in clover ETL

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, parameters

I have a query block for retrieving data from MSSQL Server. the query has some hardcoded date values which needs to be changed everyday to import the daily feed. I need to automate this execution. I am using cloverETL for executing the query right now.
Here is the query (its a query to retrieve sharepoint activity data)

```
use
DocAve_AuditDB;
DECLARE
@ParameterValue VARCHAR(100),
@SQL
VARCHAR(MAX)
SET
@SQL = STUFF((SELECT 'UNION ALL SELECT COL_ItemTypeName, COL_UserName, COL_MachineIp, COL_DocLocation, DATEADD(SECOND, COL_Occurred / 1000, ''19700101 00:00'') as Date_Occurred, COL_EventAction FROM '+ TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE DATEADD(SECOND, COL_Occurred / 1000, ''19700101 00:00'') BETWEEN '+ '''20120515'''+ 'AND' + '''20120516'''+ 'AND ' + 'COL_ItemTypeName='+ '''Document''' AS 'data()'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
TABLE_NAME LIKE '%2012_05%'
FOR
XML PATH('')),1,10,'')
EXEC
(@SQL)
```

In the above block I want the TABLE_NAME LIKE param i.e. %2012_05% to be a variable retrieved from the current data and also the date values in the between clause

> BETWEEN '+ '''20120515'''+ 'AND' + '''20120516'''
>    to be todays date-1 and todays date

should create a small java program for handling this or it can be done directly in the query itself? if yes how?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GETDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) or [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) to obtain the current date (and time).

Use [`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with the `112` format specifier to convert the current timestamp to a string formatted as `YYYYMMDD`.

Use [`DATEADD()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for calculations (like subtracting one day) on dates/times.

Use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to subtract parts from the formatted date string to rearrange them to the `%YYYY_MM%` format.

Comment: Thanks, we are going to try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use inline ctl notation in DBInputTable:

```
SELECT 'UNION ALL SELECT COL_ItemTypeName, COL_UserName, COL_MachineIp, COL_DocLocation, DATEADD(SECOND, COL_Occurred / 1000, ''19700101 00:00'') as Date_Occurred, COL_EventAction FROM `date2str(today(), "yyyy_MM")` WHERE DATEADD(SECOND, COL_Occurred / 1000, ''19700101 00:00'') BETWEEN '+ '''`date2str(today(), "yyyyMMdd")`'''+ 'AND' + '''`date2str(dateAdd(today(),1,day), "yyyyMMdd")`'''+ 'AND ' + 'COL_ItemTypeName='+ '''Document''' AS 'data()'
```